# how retrieve an already calculated CSS rule and not the calc syntax

Tags: javascript, css, calc, getcomputedstyle

here is a very little question that I can't answer easily, and I think this is strange.
I got a div with a CSS calc rule for Height

```
@media screen and ( max-device-width: 399px)
{
    :root{
    --imgItem-width: 30px;
    --imgItem-height: 55px;
    --imgNav-width: 80px;
    --imgNav-height: 35px;
    
}

.postPlace{
    height: calc(var(--imgItem-height) * 2 + 5px) ;
    --gsh : calc( var(--imgItem-height) /2 ) ;
}
```

This div is growing on user requests through a jscript. That's working.
But it's an incremental version. I store in a cookie the number of time it should grow and do it automatically.
Then when he comes back to grow again, and if the div has already been extended, I don't have the initial size of the div.
And that's the point.
In the script, I go with a standard value of 300px which is too much for a smartphone and may be not enough for a wild screen.

```
.animate({
      height:"+=300", 
      }, 1500 );
```

So I would like to get the real calc rule stored in a var, that I can read through js (or jq).
I tried getcomputedstyle but I'm not getting a calculated var, I'm getting the def of the calc (in this case "--gsh : calc( var(--imgItem-height) /2 )" and not 27px) ;

Does anyone got a little idea about this thing?

I saw some scss things around, but for a so silly thing, I fill a little upset...

Comment: `window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement, null).getPropertyValue('--imgItem-width'))` should work.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I made an edit on my purpose. I first badly explain. Jquery is getting the syntax not the result. And with your syntax, window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement, null).getPropertyValue('--gsh') I don't get anything.

Comment: Ofcourse not when reading `--gsh`, instead of `document.documentElement` (= `root:`) you retrieve the property value from the element you've assigned `postPlace` class.

Comment: never mind, I could not get it to work. I simplified all (that's sometime the best to do)  to ensure a simple calc in java, retrieving only one static var from css.